# How do I run a local, non-web Ruby script with ENV variables?

Tags: ruby, environment-variables, foreman

I have a `.env` file

```
SOME_VARIABLE=1
ANOTHER_VARIABLE=2
```

And here's `script.rb`

```
puts ENV['SOME_VARIABLE'], ENV['ANOTHER_VARIABLE']
```

I have `foreman` installed. When I run `foreman start -e .env`, there is no output. It looks like nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have foreman, but do you have a Procfile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you created Procfile for the foreman to run the task, if not you must create Procfile and below is sample code:

```
    my_proc:ruby script.rb
    # Then you can use the following command to execute 
    # foreman start my_proc -e .env
```

and will receive below output.

```
10:10:55 my_proc.1 | started with pid 1365
10:10:55 my_proc.1 | SOME_VARIABLE
10:10:55 my_proc.1 | 1
10:10:55 my_proc.1 | 2
10:10:55 my_proc.1 | ANOTHER_VARIABLE
10:10:55 my_proc.1 | exited with code 0
10:10:55 system    | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

and my script file was

```
puts "SOME_VARIABLE", ENV['SOME_VARIABLE'], ENV['ANOTHER_VARIABLE'], "ANOTHER_VARIABLE"
```

Hope this helps!

Cheers